# What is the difference between io.TeeReader and io.Copy?

Tags: go, io

`io.TeeReader` and `io.Copy` both read from a reader and write into a writer. What is the difference?

Comment: A TeeReader copies but also allows reading what is copied.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`io.Copy()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy) copies data from a source `io.Reader` to a destination `io.Writer`. And that's all. You don't get the data that was copied, it's not returned to you.

[`io.TeeReader()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#TeeReader) on the other hand does not perform the copy automatically. It just returns you an `io.Reader` which if you read from, the data you get will also be written to the `io.Writer` you pass to `io.TeeReader()`.

`io.TeeReader()` is useful if you need to copy data from a reader to a writer, but you also need the data because you want to inspect it or perform calculations on it.

For example let's say you want to copy an `io.Reader` to the standard output, but you also want to calculate the MD5 hash of the copied content. You may do it like this:

```
s := "Hello World"

r := io.TeeReader(strings.NewReader(s), os.Stdout)

h := md5.New()
if _, err := io.Copy(h, r); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("\nHash: %x", h.Sum(nil))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/dtw0HRutSA9)):

```
Hello World
Hash: b10a8db164e0754105b7a99be72e3fe5
```

Note that this can also be achieved using [`io.MultiWriter()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#MultiWriter) instead of `io.TeeReader()`:

```
s := "Hello World"

h := md5.New()
mw := io.MultiWriter(h, os.Stdout)
if _, err := io.Copy(mw, strings.NewReader(s)); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("\nHash: %x", h.Sum(nil))
```

This outputs the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Z2LeF7o7uKl).