# Why io.TeeReader provide nil object value?

Tags: go

I'm trying to run next chunk of go code to make a unique file name based on its hash and upload file to aws s3 bucket:

```
func PutImageToStore(f *bytes.Buffer) error {   
    hasher := md5.New()
    io.TeeReader(f, hasher)
    m5 := hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
    uploader := manager.NewUploader(awsS3Client)
    // put object to storage:
    result, err := uploader.Upload(context.TODO(), &s3.PutObjectInput{
            Bucket: &myS3bucket,
        Key:    &m5,
        Body:   f,
    })
    return err
}
```

where awsS3client and myS3bucket are defined globally and f is an upload object, i.e earlier:

```
file, _, _  := r.FormFile("myimage")
io.Copy(f, file)
```

As a result of

```
PutImageToStore(f)
```

I always get Key value (i.e. &m5) equal "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" which as I understand is a hash of nil.

The aws s3 upload is correct, the only issue is with the uploaded object name.

When I change the line

```
io.TeeReader(f, hasher)
```

to

```
io.Copy(hasher, f)
```

I get correct object name, but the object itself get corrupted and has 0 (zero) bytes.

So why I always get such a narrowed result for an object name?
What is a difference among io.Copy() and io.TeeReader in this case?

I looked at this example ([What is the difference between io.TeeRearder and io.Copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71523651/what-is-the-difference-between-io-teerearder-and-io-copy)), but still do not understand my case.

Comment: `io.TeeReader` isn't returning `nil`, you're not even assigning the return value from `io.TeeReader`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the `io.Reader` returned by `io.TeeReader`:

```
r := io.TeeReader(f, hasher)
```

then when you read all of `r`'s content, it will get written also to the `hasher`, so:

```
body, err := io.ReadAll(r)
```

and `body` will contain all the bytes of the file.

---

You can achieve the same without an `io.TeeReader` since you need the whole body anyway:

```
body, err := io.ReadAll(f) // check err

_, err = io.Copy(hasher, bytes.Newsreader(body)) // check err
```

Comment: Thank you, colm.anseo. 
Though I did not understand the reason of such a io.* foos behavior, your practical advice helped me to code properly.

Comment: You can achieve the same result without an `io.TeeReader` - see edited answer.