# How to print buffer to stdout but also capture as string?

Tags: go, buffer

I know how to capture the output of a `exec.Command` but I would like to also stream it to `stdout` while still capturing it.
Thanks for any input!

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("ls")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Run()
    fmt.Println(out.String())
}
```

Comment: Either using `io.TeeReader()` or `io.MultiWriter()`. For an example, see [What is the difference between io.TeeRearder and io.Copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71523651/what-is-the-difference-between-io-teerearder-and-io-copy/71524693#71524693)

Comment: `ls` may be a toy example here. But if not, it's preferred to use native `Go` APIs (like [os.ReadDir](https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadDir)) rather than launching an external executable.

Comment: @colm.anseo Yes, that was only to shorten the example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Example using [`io.MultiWriter`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#MultiWriter)

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("ls")
    var out bytes.Buffer
    w := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, &out)
    cmd.Stdout = w
    fmt.Printf("===Stdout:===\n")
    cmd.Run()
    fmt.Printf("\n===Variable:===\n")
    fmt.Println(out.String())
}
```